# Is it possible to use the truncate tag in django templates without getting the ...?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

if `value = "manbearpig"` and in templates you called `{{value|truncate:6}}` you would get a displayed value along the lines of `manbe...`.

How can I get the same result just without the `...` in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [slice filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice). It works the same as regular slicing built into Python.

```
 {{ value|slice:":6" }}
```